# How To Disable Add new users On Subsites In Multisite?

Tags: multisite, users

How To Disable "Add new user" On Subsites In WordPress Multisite ?

[image]

Comment: Why not use the "Members" plugin to disable the feature for any specific role like Admin, Editor, Author, Subscriber etc. Though it's a kind of hiding, but authentically it's kind of disabling too.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the Add Users capability from Administrators (but leave it intact for Super Administrators), you can do this:

```
<?php
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
if ( $role->capabilities['add_user'] == 1 && ! is_main_site( get_current_blog_id() ) ) {
// Because this is saved to the database, we check first
// to see if it's already been done
    $role->remove_cap['add_user'];
}
?>
```

Add the code to a plugin in the [`mu-plugins` directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) to have it run on each site (whenever the site in question is visited).

**Note** -- this will remove the capability in the database.  To restore it, you'll need to use `add_cap()`.

#### Reference

[`get_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role)
[`remove_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)
[`add_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)
[`is_main_site()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_site)
[`get_current_blog_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id)